# Using sh -c in terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, awk, objective-c

I have this command line that I enter into terminal and it works as intended:

```
dscl . -readall /Users UniqueID | awk '/^RecordName:/ {name=$2}; /^UniqueID: / {if ($2 > 500) print name}'
```

What I want to do is use sh -c "insert command string here" and when I try and use the above statement, it gives me these errors:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    /^RecordName:/ >>>  {name=} <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

Any idea how I would correct this? I need it for a program in objective-c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes don't prevent variable expansion inside double quotes:

```
$ echo "a'$RANDOM'"
a'23976'
```

You could replace `$` with `\$` or `'` with `'\''`:

```
$ sh -c "echo a b | awk '{print \$2}'"
b
$ sh -c 'echo a b | awk '\''{print $2}'\'
b
```

Or use a heredoc:

```
sh -s <<'END'
echo a b | awk '{print $2}'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `awk` command does not have a closing `'`.

Comment: My mistake, I just forgot to add that to the question but had it in my code.